# How to config .htaccess permalink

Tags: .htaccess, permalinks

I use linux and all file .html onpage:
No database:
I want to redirect this:

```
http://example.com/?page=/mylinks.html
```

to this:

```
http://example.com/mylinks.html
```

in the ".htaccess" file, or some alternative.

Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ %1 [L]
```

Comment: I have used your way and the results failed!